# Question from Propositional and First Order Logic.

Tags: propositional-calculus

Let a, b, c, d be propositions. Assume that the equivalences a ↔ (b V ~b) and b ↔ c hold. Then the truth value of the formula (a ∧ b) → ((a ∧ c) ∨ d) is always?

I solved using hint -

a ↔ (b V ~b)

a ↔ 1

And,

b ↔ c

Given equation,

(a ∧ b) → ((a ∧ c)  ∨ d)

~(a ∧ b) ∨ ((a ∧ c) ∨ d)

On putting value of above two we have,

~(1 ∧ c) ∨ ((1 ∧ c) ∨ d)

(~c ∨ c )∨ d

1 ∨ d

1

But this answer is bit difficult. So I want to ask is there any other way to solve this.

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Answer (score 0):

There are always different ways to solve it. My solution is less formal than yours but nevertheless valid reasoning:

$a \leftrightarrow (b\lor \lnot b) \Rightarrow a $ is true.

Now there are two cases.
Assume, $b$ is false. The left hand side, $(a \land b)$ is then false and thus, the whole formula is true.
Assume, $b$ is true. Then $c$ is true as well (because of $b \leftrightarrow c$) and so the right hand side, $(a \land c) \lor d$ is true and thus, the whole formula is true.

Note that a formula of kind $F \rightarrow G$ is only false when $F$ is true and $G$ is false. Whenever F is false or whenever G is true, the formula is true.

Answer (score 0):

I would say what you do is about as simply as you can get it!  Yes: use Complement to substitute $1$ for $b \lor \neg b$, and hence substitute $1$ for $a$. Also: substitute $b$ for $c$ (or vice versa). And finally, rewrite the $\rightarrow$ into $\lor$ so you can use Complement again and get your answer ... but you did all that! I really see no simpler way to do this.